# C# override a method and optionally throw an exception, is a return value required?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a method in C# 4.0 that is like this:

```
    protected override bool _update()
    {
        if (this.Notes == "")
            throw new Exception("Some message...");
        else
            base._update();
    }
```

The compiler complains that not all code paths return a value, however, if I were to do this:

```
    protected override bool _update()
    {
        throw new Exception("Some message...");
    }
```

it compiles okay. Are there recommended ways of getting around this? Seems like they really aren't all that different, if an exception in one case suffices for no return value, why wouldn't it in the other case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a shot :)

```
protected override bool _update()
    {
        if (this.Notes == "")
            throw new Exception("Some message...");
        else
            return base._update();
    }
```

You just need to return the output of base._update(), it's not enough to just run it because the value wouldn't get returned.

Comment: I'm such a doofus! Thanks for pointing that out. I assumed since base._update() already returns a bool that I was fine, but had still forgot a 'return'.

Answer (score 1):

The method is expecting a return value of boolean type, yet you're not returning anything here. The "Exception" case will exit out of the function no matter what. You need to do something like:

if(..)
..
else
{
return base._update();
}

Answer (score 0):

Because if `this.Notes != ""`, then your method would exit without ever returning a value. Did you mean this?

```
protected override bool _update()
{
    if (this.Notes == "")
        throw new Exception("Some message...");
    else
        return base._update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not doing 
"return base._update"
also please stick to standard naming conventions as a recommendation : )

Stay away from dangling if stmt issues by including

```
        protected override bool Update()
        {
            if (this.Notes == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("Some message...");
            }
            else
            {
                return base.Update();
            }
        }
```